# Remove only selected elements from html dom

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove all the elements except one from a div when clicking on a buttom. How do I do this with jQuery?

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="inner1"></div>
<div id="inner2"></div>    
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('div1').html(' ');
});
```

It removes all the elements within **div1**, but I want to remove only **inner1**.

Comment: [Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: `$(selectionToRemove).not(selectionToKeep).remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#inner1').remove();
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D7hdx/)

See: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 1):

This will remove everything except `#inner2`, including text nodes.

```
var $inner2 = $("#inner2");

$('#div1').empty().append($inner2);
```

Comment: @tallboy The question is how to remove all elements except one, not to remove just one as the other answer do.  `$("#div1").children(":not(#inner2)").remove()` would leave behind text nodes.

Comment: I see, it appears to be just a poorly worded question. At the bottom he says he only wants to remove `inner1`

Comment: @tallboy Yeah, the original question is considerably more interesting than what appears to be the actual question.

Comment: yes i just want to remove only one element inner1 when click on a button so that inner2 doesn't get removed from the html dom.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Out of curiosity is there a reason to do this instead of using .not() - http://api.jquery.com/not/ - to remove the element you want to keep from the selected items? Is it more performant? .contents() also includes text nodes.

Comment: @pwdst `contents` won't work.  http://jsfiddle.net/Byayz/  Once you use `not` then the text nodes are no longer included.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#div1 #inner1').remove();`

This will remove the `inner1` div from `div1`.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for?  `$('#inner1').remove();`
You may want to look into jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/remove/
If this doesn't answer your question, please create a jsfiddle link